# Change web page contents before it gets displayed to the user using php

Tags: php, html

buttons.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>
        Button Page
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <button name="btn1">Button 1</button>
    <button name="btn2">Button 2</button>
    <button name="btn2">Button 3</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and the result.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>
        Result Page
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="parag1">This value is for Button1</p>
    <p class="parag2">This value is for Button1</p>
    <p class="parag3">This value is for Button1</p>
</body>
</html>
```

what I want to happen is when the user clicks a button, the paragraphs in the result.php will change to values assigned for that button before it gets displayed to the user. Thanks!

Comment: before the script brings the user to the result.php the values for <p> tags in result.php has changed.

Comment: you should be using a form for that

Comment: You haven't tried anything, your question is vague and there's no PHP whatsoever here? Anyways, to get you started *(and if I understand what you're trying to achieve)* you would want to first of all make a form `POST` in `buttons.php` and then `GET` the values submitted in `results.php`.

Answer (score 1):

First off I would recommend looking into PHP POST and GET methods, they will give you a more complete picture of how form data can be passed from one page to another.

Regarding your question all you would need to do here is wrap each button in a form like so:

```
 <form action="results.php" method="POST">
    <button name="btn1">Button 2</button>
 </form>
<form action="results.php"method="POST">
    <button name="btn2">Button 2</button>
 </form>
<form action="results.php" method="POST">
    <button name="btn3">Button 3</button>
 </form>
```

I would recommend using a hidden value that is readonly and changing your button to a submit, this will allow you to hide the values you would like to pass across and stop unwanted editing of the values by the users.

e.g.

```
<form action="results.php" method="POST">
    <input readonly type="hidden" name="buttonValueOne" value="Button 1"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btn1">Button 1/>
</form>
<form action="results.php"method="POST">
    <input readonly type="hidden" name="buttonValueTwo" value="Button 2"/>
    <input type="submit" name="btn2">Button 2/>
</form>
<form action="results.php" method="POST">
   <input readonly type="hidden" name="buttonValueThree" value="Button 3"/>
   <input type="submit" name="btn3">Button 3/>
</form>
```

Then on the results page, you would use if statements to check which one was passed over:

```
    if (isset($_POST["buttonValueOne"]) { ?>
      <p class="parag1"><?php echo $_POST['buttonValueOne']; ?></p>
   <?php
       }
    ?>
```